WIX fullfiler access control
In wix ecommerce website we handling the fullfilment with the third party service provider. So we added a account as a fullfiler and with that account while he logs in he directly taken to orders page and he will be adding the tracking number and saves.
Till that is fine
But we found some other settings and features are being shown for that account 
We need to restrict all the features and the fullfiler hass to able to access only the order page for this shipping work.
Is that possible?
